# Expose and add QWebView widget object to QML

Tags: c++, qt, types, webview, qml

QML has a type called 'WebView', this thing is also known as 'QQuickWebView'. But 'QQuickWebView' is not compatible with 'QWebView' (which is a widget component, not QML type).

I want to access and modify 'WebView' in C++ but the closest class that I can cast for WebView is 'QQuickItem'.

Any solution to make QWebView embeddable in QML?

Comment: what are you aiming to do ? give an illustrative example if possbile .

Comment: i want to use QML to create my application, but i also want to use QWebView instead of QQuickWebView because the QWebView of qt widgets is more powerful than the QQuickWebView of qt qml

Comment: check this [QtWebKit.experimental](http://rschroll.github.io/beru/2013/08/21/qtwebview.experimental.html) maybe useful.

Comment: thank you, "import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0" seems working

Comment: @Redanium, pls add QtWebKit.experimental as answer so i can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In QML, use "import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0"

Reference:
http://rschroll.github.io/beru/2013/08/21/qtwebview.experimental.html